# How to install devicemapper and brtfs header files?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install the libdevicemapper and brtfs header files on my 16.04:

```
$ apt-cache search libdevmapper-dev
libdevmapper-dev - Linux Kernel Device Mapper header files
$ sudo apt-get install libdevmapper-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdevmapper-dev : Depends: libudev-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu4) but 229-4ubuntu13 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f libudev1 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libudev1 is already the newest version (229-4ubuntu13).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I can't find `brtfs` at all.

Comment: Please try  this command `sudo apt install libudev1=229-4ubuntu4`

Comment: @ali76, but then I won't have the latest libudev

Comment: For installing `libudev-dev` you need `229-4ubuntu4` version of this package, So you can't install the latest version of `libudev1` and install `libudev-dev` at the same time

Comment: @ali76, how do people have `devicemapper` and `brtfs` on the same time working on latest machine?

Comment: Because of this link https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libudev-dev&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all the latest version of `libudev-dev` is `229-4ubuntu4` . I guess you've install `229-4ubuntu13` from something like ppa. \\ Please try the latest packages of official Ubuntu repositories .

Comment: @ali76 I see but how docker developer or any other projects works on the latest version?

Comment: But if you want to be up to date you can use the latest version of Ubuntu (17.04) , that have `232-21ubuntu2` version of this package

Comment: Some projects are supporting this version of `libudev1` But as `apt` output says `libudev-dev` not support this. // I don't know why this package not support but you can ask the reason of this problem from its developers